# Where is the Terminal in VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio

I am running 16.3.4 so I assume it already should include updates from an earlier preview version?
Mentioned here
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/

This is all I see under the 'View' menu

[image]

...and this under 'Other windows'
[image]

See this in the 'preview  features' section of Environment.  Terminal nowhere to be found?

[image]

Comment: `View > Terminal Window` not work? You've enabled it right?

Comment: Updated post, see screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the blog [article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/say-hello-to-the-new-visual-studio-terminal/) -

> This new preview experience is part of Visual Studio version 16.3
>   **Preview** 3.

So the Terminal is not available in Visual Studio version 16.3.4.
Also, I installed Visual Studio Professional 2019 preview version 16.4.0 Preview 1.0 and the Terminal is still in there.