# Cannot find Terminal Window in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Contrary to all the documentation I've seen, "Experimental VS Terminal Window" does not show up in Preview Features in VS 2019.  How then do I add it so it will show up under the "View" menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the Terminal in VS 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58346980/where-is-the-terminal-in-vs-2019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this from MS :-(.

> Thank you for your feedback. At the moment, Integrated Terminal is
> only available via preview releases (through the Preview Channel) for
> 16.4+. Therefore it’s expected that you see this for 16.5 (Preview) but not 16.4 (release).
>
> Thanks,
>
> Tina

Comment: You should post the link where the quote came from. Besides, that's outdated information. Terminal was included in the release channel since [16.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-6-and-v16-7-preview-1-ship-today/).